# Angular 5 firestore geopoint displays [object object]

Tags: location, google-cloud-firestore, angular5

I need a code example on how to display GeoPoint on my web page listing. I create the geopoint in my android app but it shows up as [object object] on my web display. It is defined as a string in my model. I can find some good examples of creating the geopoint in angular 5 but it is necessary to take my phone to the job site and create it there so the lady in charge in the office can verify that I was there.
I am new to anglular 5 but have put together a pretty good web page.
I am grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.GeoPoint). Once you have a document with a `GeoPoint` property you can access the `latitude` and `longitude` properties. For example, if your data looks like this in your console:

[image]

... then you can access the location like this:

```
var docRef = db.collection("cities").doc("QGy13BvW4CSLH9CN9rkI");

docRef.get().then(function(doc) {
  var myGeoProperty = doc.data().location;
  console.log("Latitude:", myGeoProperty.latitude);
  console.log("Longitude:", myGeoProperty.longitude);
});
```

Also note that the datatype in my example is `geopoint` (red circle).

For displaying a geographic location, I recommend a component like [Angular Google Maps (AGM)](https://angular-maps.com/guides/getting-started/). If you watch their getting started cideo end to end it walks you through the setup including getting a Google Maps API key. In the end it boils down to having an Angular `@Component` that has a `<agm-map ...>` in its template. Instead of logging the latitude and longitude the the console you then set properties of your component that you have bound. For example:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-map-component',
  styles: ['agm-map { height: 480px; }'],
  template: '<agm-map [latitude]="geoLat" [longitude]="geoLong"></agm-map>'
})
export class MyMapComponent implements OnInit {
  geoLat: number = 0.0;
  geoLong: number = 0.0;

  ngOnInit() {
    // init "db" etc.

    let docRef = db.collection("cities").doc("QGy13BvW4CSLH9CN9rkI");

    docRef.get().then(doc => {
      let myGeoProperty = doc.data().location;
      this.geoLat  = myGeoProperty.latitude;
      this.geoLong = myGeoProperty.longitude;
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: With some manipulation, I was able to add the above code to my service component.

Comment: var docRef = afs.collection("woodyplants").doc("toJursfsMcf0MqmQcSLn");

docRef.ref.get().then(function(doc) {
//docRef.collection(function(doc) {
  var myGeoProperty = doc.data().myGeoProperty;  
  console.log("Latitude:", myGeoProperty.latitude);
  console.log("Longitude:", myGeoProperty.longitude);
});
//
}

Comment: @rosey Not sure what to make of your comment, only that your collection and document have different ids than in my example, but that your document, surprisingly, has a property with exactly the same name ("myGeoProperty"). Please let me know if I can clarify anything.

Comment: It is placed under the constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore){ Could you advise me as to the proper location.  ...

Comment: What should I replace myGeoProperty with?

Comment: Thank you Tilo and I am seeing the  coordinates on the console. So what you have given me is working. What I cannot do is get the latitude and longitude to show up on web page. All fields appear normal but how do I get latitude and longitude to appear. Is pipe a possiblity? Thank you for hanging in there..

Comment: @rosey I made another edit to show how to display a location in a map.

Comment: I could not get the above to work so when the geopoint is created, I extract the latitude and longitude as separate fields and it works fine and probably saves space and time.